# Amadeus Self Service Api Booking

Tags: api, amadeus

Does the Amadeus Sefl-Service developer api have booking methods for the Flight and Hotel Apis?

Answer (score 0):

We do not offer booking capabilities for the time being. We are constantly working on improving our API catalog and offering booking capabilities is one of the options we are analyzing.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Can you say if these future releases are within this year?